# Developing with Caffenol

Tags: developing

My first roll of 120 Ilford 400 developed with caffenol. 9 minutes of development time as indicated at Caffenol.org

Image is weak, there is no clear areas in the image, and the overall film is still grey on one side and tan on the other.

I assume under exposed. Does anyone have an idea of how far to extend the dev time?

Comment: What  Instant  Coffee  are you using.   If I remember correctly there is only one instant coffee that produces good results. I think it’s Nescafé but possibly could be Folgers.  You really need to do a lot of tests with each film and  development  times to work out the best combo.

Comment: I doubt it's Folgers. Caffenol is used globally and I haven't seen Folgers here across the pond, ever

Comment: And a side note... "Ilford 400" is quite meaningless, just like "Kodak 400" or anything such. There a more than 1 ISO 400 films

Comment: @timvrhn Since there is only one Ilford film *named* something along the line of Ilford 400 (Ilford Delta 400), this is the only film from Ilford with a mentioned development time of 9 minutes on caffenol.org and the only other ISO 400 film from Ilford (HP5+) behaves very similar when developed in Caffenol, the question makes very much sense as stated.

Comment: Are you sure that your films are correctly exposed? Do they look all right when developed in a proper developer as recommended by the manufacturer? Without knowing that, it is difficult to say if you have incorrectly exposed the film, done something wrong when mixing your Caffenol or developed too short.

Comment: @jarnbjo I beg to disagree. It's very common for new film shooters to name the film they're shooting as whatever ISO is printed on the box. OP might as well be well-experienced, but I'm saying it's unclear and could lead to confusion :)